# Swift Date part in tableview cell

Tags: swift, swift2

I am using custom tablevıew cell and I want to add date or time part between two cell if it is necessary.

How can I add date or time between two cells like my screenshoot?

[image]

Comment: you can do it at the tableviewsectionheader. Detect if it is a new day or to your own preferred logic, and add the date.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to separate your datasource into multiple sections and add headers or footers for the same. Check this link out

[Custom headers and footers for UITableView](http://www.accella.net/knowledgebase/custom-header-and-footer-views-for-uitableviews/)